# ‘GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.’ throw when Face Detection in Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, face-detection

Each time when I run face detection in Python. It'll throw

> GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.

The below codes are my Python program  *haar_face_detect.py* :

> ```
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
>
> from numpy import *
> import numpy as np
> import cv2
>
> face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
> img = cv2.imread('./G20_pictures/7.jpg')    
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 1)
>
> for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
>         img2 = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),4)
>         roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
>         roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
> cv2.imshow('img',img)
> print(len(faces))
>
> cv2.waitKey(0)
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> cv2.imwrite("save.jpg", img)
> ```

However, the below sentences will be appeared every time follow run  *haar_face_detect.py*  :

> ```
> $ python haar_face_detect.py 
> GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
> init done 
> opengl support available 
> 25
> ```

Then the program will keep running, can not stop, as if stuck the same. The process can only be terminated by forcibly closing.
Could you please advise me how I can solve this problem? I need detailed instruction to run these commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Any fix to this problem? I am facing the same thing now.

Comment: @JeshKundem did you got the solution of this issue?

Comment: @Bushan NO I did not

Comment: Do you happen to be using Anaconda?